# service method as twig global variable

Tags: php, symfony, service, global-variables, twig

In my symfony2 application, I have a getPorfolioUser method which return a specific user variable.

I am looking forward to be able to call

> {% if portfolio_user %}

in twig. I did not understand how I could set this as a global variable as from the documentation I am under the impression I can only set fixed elements or services but not services' methods.

Am I obliged to write an extension or a helper for that ?
What the simpler way of doing this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can define your custom service as `twig globals variable` as follow:

## in the config.yml

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    globals:
        myGlobaService: "@acme.demo_portfolio_service"  #The id of your service
```

## Use it a Twig file

```
{% if myGlobaService.portfolio_user() %}
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 8):

One approach is use a CONTROLLER event listener.  I like to use CONTROLLER instead of REQUEST because it ensures that all the regular request listeners have done their thing already.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class ProjectEventListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array
    (
        KernelEvents::CONTROLLER => array(
            array('onControllerProject'),
        ),
    );
}
private $twig;
public function __construct($twig)
{
    $this->twig = $twig;
}
public function onControllerProject(FilterControllerEvent $event)
{
    // Generate your data
    $project = ...;

    // Twig global
    $this->twig->addGlobal('project',$project);    
}

# services.yml
cerad_project__project_event_listener:
    class: ...\ProjectEventListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
    arguments:
        - '@twig'
```

Listeners are documented here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html

Another approach would be to avoid the twig global altogether and just make a twig extension call.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Either way works well.

Answer (score 1):

When you look here :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#app

You can read this :

> The app variable is available everywhere and gives access to many
>   commonly needed objects and values. It is an instance of
>   GlobalVariables.

`GlobalVariables` is `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\GlobalVariables`

I never do it but I think one way is to overide this class in order to put your special needs in.

Answer (score -1):

I was having some difficult with this as well and finally solved it by doing the following:

1. Setup your bundle (e.g: MyVendor/MyBundle)

   ```
   $ app/console generate:bundle
   ```

2. In your bundle directory, create **MyService.php** class file in the **DependencyInjection** folder.

3. In this class file, create the function

   ```
   public function getExample(){
       return "it works!!!";
   }
   ```

4. In **app/config/services.yml** create a new service like so:

   ```
   myvendor.mybundle.myservice
         class: MyVendor\MyBundle\DependencyInjection\MyService
   ```

5. In **app/config/config.yml** under the **twig** configuration section

   ```
   twig:
       globals:
           mystuff: '@myvendor.mybundle.myservice'
   ```

6. Then in your twig templates you can reference the variable like so:

   ```
    {{ mystuff.example }}
   ```

**DISCLAIMER**

this is just how I got it to work....

hope this helps.