# Symfony add a service that depends on TemplateEngine in twig.globals

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I want to inject a service in each view, but this service depends on `EngineInterface` so I cannot add it to `twig.globals` as it throws an error of circular reference.

Here is an example:

The service:

namespace AppBundle\Utils;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface;

```
class Test
{
    /** @var EngineInterface */
    private $template;

    /**
     * Test constructor.
     * @param $template
     */
    public function __construct(EngineInterface $template)
    {
        $this->template = $template;
    }

    public function render(){
        return $this->template->render('AppBundle::test.html.twig');
    }
}
```

And in config.yml:

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
    globals:
        test: "@AppBundle\\Utils\\Test"
```

And the error shown:

[image: twig circular reference error]

So, how can I inject this service in all views. Of course I could inject the container and get the templating service from the container, but I would like to avoid the container injection.

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure, but your question looks like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/242284)

Comment: Have you considered using a twig extension?  You might run into the same problem.  Not sure.  You could also make a kernel listener which would inject your service into the twig globals object and avoid using config.yml.   See my answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28862801/service-method-as-twig-global-variable

Comment: Try using setter injection. I remember having the same problem, but I cannot recall how I solved it.

Comment: @Pete using a setter works fine, although I would prefer to define the requierment in the constructor. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your service basically just includes the `test.html.twig` template into another template.

Twig already provides a built-in function for that. Instead of

```
{{ test.render() }}
```

You could just do this for the same effect, but without the need for a custom service:

```
{{ include('AppBundle::test.html.twig') }}
```

If you don't want to provide the template every time you can create a macro in a "util.twig" template file:

```
{% macro render() %}
    {{ include('AppBundle::test.html.twig') }}
{% endmacro %}
```

and use it in your template:

```
{% import "util.twig" as util %}

...

{{ util.render() }}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, in the example it justs renders a template, but in the real service that I am implementing, this function handles more logic, and can render several templates and at the end it returns an html code to be added to the template that has called it. So `include` and the `macro` would not fit.

Comment: And all the additional logic can't be done in a separate template file instead of a service? It is hard to give a fitting answer, if we don't know the exact use case.

Comment: Moving the logic of the app to a view is not a good idea, as then this logic will not belong to the service itself.

Comment: But what is your service actually doing? "Rendering several templates" can be done within the template itself, as in my answer. If you need complex logic to decide which template(s) to render, you can create a custom twig function, returning the name of the template(s) to render. You won't need the template engine dependency then. (If that is the case for you, then I could add it to the answer).

Comment: It's a service that is part of another service. It queries database to fetch data and pocess this data to build a hmtl code to be used by the service that is including it. This service is a service that I need in all views. I've solved using the setter option instead of the constructor. This doesn't throw a circular exception.