# How do I add a twig global from a bundle config?

Tags: symfony, twig

I'd like my bundle to inject a twig global from its config.

```php
class MyBundle extends AbstractBundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container): void
    {
        parent::build($container);
        $container->addCompilerPass(new TwigPass());
    }
    public function loadExtension(array $config, ContainerConfigurator $container, ContainerBuilder $builder): void
    { 
        $theme = $config['theme']; // how to make this a twig global?
        // $twig = $builder->getDefinition('twig'); // NOPE! Twig isn't loaded yet.
    }
```

The compiler pass gets twig, which isn't available when my bundle extension is loading.

```php
class TwigPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (false === $container->hasDefinition('twig')) {
            return;
        }
        
        $theme = 'theme_from_config';
        $def = $container->getDefinition('twig');
        $def->addMethodCall('addGlobal', ['theme', $theme]);
```

I'm missing something, or something is out of order.  How can the compiler pass get the config data from the extension?  Or if that's not the right approach, how can I inject a twig global from my bundle config?

Comment: I'm not too sure but just throwing an idea out. Could you generate and load a new yaml config file [so it is like this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html) from your bundle?

Comment: This may be a good read also, [modifying the config of another bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/configuration.html#modifying-the-configuration-of-another-bundle), the Twig bundle in this case..

Comment: You can do it with a [controller listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28862801/service-method-as-twig-global-variable/28863725#28863725).  But it is definitely worth looking at the prepend method for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to make config data available to a pass is to add the data to the container as a parameter:

```
class TwigPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (false === $container->hasDefinition('twig')) {
            return;
        }
        $theme = $container->getParameter('my.theme');

        $def = $container->getDefinition('twig');
        $def->addMethodCall('addGlobal', ['theme', $theme]);
    }
}
class CeradMyBundle extends AbstractBundle

    public function loadExtension(array $config, ContainerConfigurator $container, ContainerBuilder $builder): void
    {
        $container->parameters()->set('my.theme', $config['theme']);
    }
```

To actually get your theme config value into the $config array requires making a Configure class.  Fortunately AbstractBundle can simplify this with a configure method:

```
# config/packages/cerad_my.yaml
cerad_my:
  theme: theme_from_config_file

class CeradMyBundle extends AbstractBundle

  public function configure(DefinitionConfigurator $definition): void
  {
      $definition->rootNode()
          ->children()
              ->scalarNode('theme')->defaultValue('theme_default')->end()
          ->end()
      ;
  }
```

After getting this to work, it was a tiny bit annoying to have that one extra DI class i.e. TwigPass so I stole a trick from the Kernel and just had the AbstractBundle implement the pass interface:

```
class CeradMyBundle extends AbstractBundle implements CompilerPassInterface
{
  public function build(ContainerBuilder $container): void
  {
      // Register as a pass
      $container->addCompilerPass($this);
  }
  public function loadExtension(array $config, ContainerConfigurator $container, ContainerBuilder $builder): void
  {
    $container->parameters()
      ->set('my.theme', $config['theme']);
  }
  public function configure(DefinitionConfigurator $definition): void
  {
      $definition->rootNode()
          ->children()
              ->scalarNode('theme')->defaultValue('theme_default')->end()
          ->end()
      ;
  }
  // The compiler pass
  public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
  {
      if (false === $container->hasDefinition('twig')) {
          return;
      }
      $theme = $container->getParameter('my.theme');
      $def = $container->getDefinition('twig');
      $def->addMethodCall('addGlobal', ['theme', $theme]);
  }
}
```

If you follow this approach then you can actually save your theme as a property in your bundle class and avoid the need to add a public parameter.  Your choice.

Comment: I love the trick to get rid of the extra DI (TwigPass).  Symfony 6.1 made bundle configuration so much easier, but the CompilerPass always felt awkward.  Quite slick, thanks for posting, @Cerad